# Clang line directive

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, clang++

I'm writing a syntax translator that outputs C++ code and have run into an interesting issue. Say I have two files: `ln.x` and `ln.cpp`. In `ln.x`:

```
abc
```

In `ln.cpp`:

```
#line 1 "ln.x"
(
```

When I try to compile it using GCC, it prints the corresponding line in `ln.x`:

```
ln.x:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
 abc
 ^
ln.x:1:1: error: expected ‘)’ at end of inpu
```

However, Clang simply prints the line of the same file:

```
ln.x:1:2: error: expected unqualified-id
(
 ^
ln.x:1:2: error: expected ')'
ln.x:1:1: note: to match this '('
(
^
2 errors generated.
```

Is there a way to get Clang to print the line of the file like GCC?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. As far as I can tell, the compiler is entirely justified in complaining, as a file consisting of nothing but a single opening parenthesis is not valid C++.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?  That isn't C++ code, so what does "get around this" mean?

Comment: @DrewDormann I clarified my question.

Comment: I would prefer the clang diagnostic here. It says what was wrong. The gcc diagnostic, in contrast, is entirely misleading and might cause the programmer to waste much time trying to track down the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a bug than a feature. Why do you want it?

Printing from the file nominated by `#line` only works as long as the line matches the text getting parsed, character-for-character. And if the file exists in the first place.

I don’t see anything about this in the GCC preprocessor manual (GCC 4.9 edition). However, there is a note that once upon a time (up to 2001), GCC would assume that the named file really existed locally, or at least that its parent directory existed. This could be a holdover bug.

And, no, there's no way to get Clang to do this. It has no concept of attempting to open the file named by `#line`.

Answer (score 1):

So, since this seemingly isn't possible, I wrote a [Perl script to wrap Clang and rewrite the error lines](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/reclang). Kind of hackish, but good enough for now.